# In-App Purchase Store UI Requirement

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Apples storekit docs state the following requirement for in-app purchases:

"Implement a user interface for your app’s store, using the instances of SKProduct returned by the App Store. Start with a simple inteface during development, such as a table view or a few buttons."

Can anyone expand on specifically what is required here? Is it suffice to simply put an upgrade button which executes all of the storekit code or do I have to make a separate product page for a simple app upgrade?

Comment: It depends on where you put it.

Comment: I usually see it in the settings page.

Comment: I planned on putting it on the home page of my app. Am I required to explain the specific features of the upgrade? Is that what they are getting at?

Comment: You should explain what the "pro" version gets you, so you can entice them into buying it.

Comment: That's probably not a bad idea. Originally I was going to have them discover on their own what functionality is not included but now that I think about it, having a page dedicated to this is in my best interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes you should explain exactly what the upgraded version of your app does. Users won't spend money unless they know exactly what they're getting.

And for your second question, I think you should put it on a separate page. No one likes blatant advertising. For example, a settings page would be ok. People looking for advanced functionality will often check the settings page to turn on more features etc.